How to measure the performance of prediction when we are interested in the pattern of a time series?
I am wondering how can we measure the prediction performance when we are interested in the pattern of a time series rather than the level.
For example, suppose that there is a observed time series $$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4\}.$$
Here, we want to predict the zigzag pattern of the sixth to tenth values of the series $$\{4, 3, 4, 5, 4\},$$
and consider that we have two prediction results
$$\{4, 4, 4, 4, 4\}\quad \textrm{and} \quad \{10, 9, 10, 11, 10\}.$$
Then, even though the second one is actually better than the first one (because we are interested in the pattern of the series), the traditional measure such as RMSE is smaller in the first one: $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}(0^2+1^2+0^2+1^2+0^2)}=\sqrt{2/5}\;\;\; vs \;\;\; \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}(6^2+6^2+6^2+6^2+6^2)}=\sqrt{180/5}$$
So, how can we measure the prediction performance when we are interested in the pattern of a time series rather than the level?

How about looking at differences? Or do you have more complicated patterns in mind?

It really depends on what you mean by "pattern", and how you operationalize whether the "pattern" of the forecast is "close" to the "pattern" of the actuals.
For instance, if you consider a forecast $\hat{y}_t$ "good" if it is an affine linear transform of the actuals $y_t$, then you can simply run a regression of the actuals on the forecasts, $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1\hat{y}_t+\epsilon_t$, and assess the $R^2$ of this model. In your example, such a regression would yield a perfect fit and $R^2=1$.
